# How to send delayed messages twilio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm trying to send delayed messages through twilio based on a time that the user specifies on a ruby on rails application. What is the best way to accomplish this? Which gem(s) should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [twilio-ruby](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) gem before and it works great

Twilio do not allow you to schedule sms delivery directly via their API, however a workaround is to use a background job in your rails app to send the sms at at specified time, for example you could use [Sidekiq's Scheduled Jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs)